# Fill table from dropdown selection with PHP and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Thanks for looking at my problem.

Here's the goal. I have created two drop-down lists that are dynamically filled from a database. The query pulls name and phone number (and will pull more data in the future).

I'm trying to run a dynamic comparison where the user can select an item from each drop-down list and compare the additional data about their two selections in a table below.

I'd like to use AJAX so the user didn't need to keep reloading the page. I'm using wordpress which seems (at least to me) to complicate the matter. Here is my code for the two drop-down lists. Not sure how to proceed with pulling the additional data. I've been fumbling around with tutorials but haven't even come close.

```
global $wpdb;
$customers = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT name, phone FROM customers;");

foreach($customers as $c){
echo "<option value='name'>".$c->name."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
echo "<select>";
foreach($customers as $c){
echo "<option value='name'>".$c->name."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: Currently you have the `value` attributes of the `<option>` elements all set to "name". You will want to set them to the primary key values of the customer rows.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pseudo procedure for your problem.

**Step One**

Since you are using wordpress to power your application, you cannot use the standard way of using ajax where you connect to a PHP URL to poll the data! You should add the following code to your function PHP in order to access the given Ajax layer in wordpress

```
function example_ajax_request(){
 //something you want to do inside this function and return json data
 die(); //closes the ajax request
}
add_action('wp_ajax_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request');
```

Note the `wp_ajax` before the function name. This has to be added in order to work.

**Step Two**

When you get the ajax response from the server, just do your stuff from javascript to put upd the necessary data.

```
$.ajax({
    url: <? php admin_url('admin-ajax.php') ?>,
    data: {
        'action':'example_ajax_request',
    },
    success:function(data) {
        // This outputs the result of the ajax request
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

The complicated part is to get connected to the Wordpress Ajax layer. Ajax URL is the URL to your wordpress `admin-ajax.php` url. You would need to map the action to the function name you've written in the function PHP.